# JavaFX event in controller not invoked

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I'm trying to detect mouse press on canvas control. I have defined the canvas id and the OnMousePressed event in Scene Builder 8.2, but the event in the controller class (code below) is not invoked. Can you spot something wrong ?
Thanks in advnce.

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable 
{
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
    {
        assert fxid_Canvas != null : "fx:id=\"fxid_Canvas\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'FXMLDocument.fxml'.";
    }    

    @FXML
    private Canvas fxid_Canvas;

    @FXML
    void canvas_OnMousePressed(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        event.consume(); // * * * NOT invoked !
    }
}
```

Comment: The mouse-pressed event handler takes a `MouseEvent`, not `ActionEvent`. I'd expect the method isn't just not getting invoked but actually throwing exceptions.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.
And unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them